# iPhone - int to NSData?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdata

I'm making an iPhone app where I want to save state of the Application. This includes an int property which I'm persisting to a file on its own. I have it written and working, but I know the way I did it was a bit hacky, converting the int to a String and then NSData. Can anybody suggest a better way?

```
int someInt = 1;
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",someInt];
NSData *someData = [aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[someData writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"someFile"] atomically:YES];
```

And then reading it from disk and putting it back into an int -

```
NSData* someData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"someFile"]];
NSString *aString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:someData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
int someInt = [aString intValue];
```

Comment: At least one other person basically agrees (http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2002/Jun/msg01317.html).  Though they started with NSNumber, which bypasses the format step.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To write:

```
int i = 1;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes: &i length: sizeof(i)];
[data writeToFile: [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString: @"someFile"] atomically: YES]
```

and to read back:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString: @"someFile"]];
int i;
[data getBytes: &i length: sizeof(i)];
```

However, you really should be using `NSUserDefaults` for something like this, in which case you'd be doing:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: i forKey: @"someKey"]
```

to write, and

```
int i = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: @"someKey"];
```

to read.

Comment: Isn't NSUserDefaults just for user preferences that are adjusted in the preferences app?

Comment: No; although you can, it's also safe (and common) to store app behavior information there, even if there is no user interface available.  Safari on OS X uses the user defaults to save things such as last window size, whether developer features are enabled, and so on.

Comment: I have integer `int val=22136` using this method to convert to NSData, the output is: `0x78560000` but to validate my result is correct I use windows programmer calculator, the output of DEC value 22136 to HEX is `5678'. any idea why there's difference? thanks!!